# siunitx and alignat?

Tags: amsmath, siunitx, alignat

This is probably easy to do, but I can't figure out how. I have a group of equations that I have managed to vertically align using the `alignat` environment. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode = text, output-decimal-marker={,}, detect-mode, detect-shape, group-digits = integer, binary-units=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
& I_{A}           && = \mathit{SSA}/\mathit{SST}  && = \SI{99,25}{\percent}\\
& I_{B}           && = \mathit{SSB}/\mathit{SST}  && = \SI{0,35}{\percent}\\
& I_{\mathit{AB}} && = \mathit{SSAB}/\mathit{SST} && = \SI{0,40}{\percent}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

I'd like to have the numbers in the last column aligned on the decimal marker, just like `siunitx` would do in a table. In other words, I want the '0' of 0,35% to be aligned with the second '9' of 99,25%. Is that possible?

Comment: Is there always the same number of decimals? Because in that case I'd just add an extra alignment column and have the `\SI` right aligned (adding a ` = {} & \SI{..}{...} &` should be enough)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
& I_{A}           && = \mathit{SSA}/\mathit{SST}  && ={} &\SI{99,25}{\percent}&\\
& I_{B}           && = \mathit{SSB}/\mathit{SST}  && = &\SI{0,35}{\percent}&\\
& I_{\mathit{AB}} && = \mathit{SSAB}/\mathit{SST} && = &\SI{0,40}{\percent}&
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

The extra `{}` is to make the spacing after the last `=` correct.

BTW: since you did not share a full minimal example, I did not replicate getting comma into the output. Please always share a full minumal example instead of sniplets.

[image]

Comment: I've edited the question with the MWE. I guess it wouldn't make sense to have different numbers of decimals for every row, so I think this solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}  % col. type for binary and relational operators
\newenvironment{myarray}[1]{%  % define a customized 'array' environment
   \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
   \begin{array}{#1}}{%
   \end{array}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode = text, output-decimal-marker={,}, 
         detect-mode, detect-shape, 
         group-digits = integer, binary-units=true}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{myarray}{@{} lClCr @{}}
 I_{A} &=& \mathit{SSA}/\mathit{SST} &=& \SI{99,25}{\percent}\\
 I_{B} &=& \mathit{SSB}/\mathit{SST} &=& \SI{0,35}{\percent}\\
 I_{\mathit{AB}} &=& \mathit{SSAB}/\mathit{SST} &=& \SI{0,40}{\percent}
\end{myarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

**eddit:**
sorry but at uploading my answer, i was interrupted ... and than [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) overtake me for one minute with similar idea ... however, some details the mine answer are different (and simpler?):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{llcS[table-format=2.2,
                   table-space-text-post={\,\%},
                   output-decimal-marker={,}]<{\,\%}
             }
I_{A}           & = \mathit{SSA}/\mathit{SST}  & = & 99.25  \cr
I_{B}           & = \mathit{SSB}/\mathit{SST}  & = &  0.35  \cr
I_{\mathit{AB}} & = \mathit{SSAB}/\mathit{SST} & = &  0.40  \cr
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: just curious ... why use `\cr` rather than `\\ `?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, because of `%` in the last column. this is described in `siunitx` documentation: *7.13 Adding items after the last column of a tabular*, page 66.

Comment: thanks.  wasn't aware of that, not being a `siunitx` user.